# vue.js: process spread operator in template section

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs

- There is a vue.js-project that building via webpack + babel + vue-loader
- Babel plugin `transform-object-rest-spread` is used
- I use spread operator (`a = {...b, ...c}`) in `<script>` section of `.vue` files and it works correctly (compile to `_extends({}, a, b)`)
- I want to use [library](https://github.com/cometchat-pro/cometchat-pro-vue-ui-kit)
- The library use spread operator in `<template>` section: [example](https://github.com/cometchat-pro/cometchat-pro-vue-ui-kit/blob/master/src/components/Groups/CometChatViewGroupMemberListItem/CometChatViewGroupMemberListItem.vue#L59)
- Build with this library leads to `invalid expression: Unexpected token`
- Spread operators in `<script>` don't lead to error
- I pulled and built [test project](https://github.com/cometchat-pro/javascript-vue-chat-app) of the library and it has built without errors
- Version of `vue-template-compiler` is equal for both project
- I don't understand which package is processing spread operator in `<template>`

Comment: Can you show your own code that has the problem? Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: Yes: sharing a problemtic (example) is important. This operation should work in Vue CLI project without any additional setup (if yours is not a Vue CLI project, then it might not - but the example could clear it up)